# Getting Error: "pointer being freed was not allocated" when trying to delete a pointer in my deconstruction

Tags: c++, xcode, pointers

This is the deconstruction in question. "next" is of type Tile*.

```
Tile::~Tile() {
if (next != NULL)
    delete next;
next = NULL;
return;
}
```

I've been messing with issues in my project all day, and I haven't been able to find a solution to this.

Here's the full project: http://pastebin.com/azqensiP

Here is the destructor calling that destructor:

```
Boneyard::~Boneyard() {
    Tile* current = front;
    while (size != 0) {
        current = front;
        while (front != NULL) {
            if (current -> getNext() == NULL) {
                remove(current->getIndex());
            } else {
                current = current -> getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The function it's calling:

```
void List::remove(int x) {
    if (front == NULL) {
        return;
    } else if (front -> getIndex() == x) {
        Tile* temp = front;
        if (front -> getNext() != NULL)
            front = front -> getNext();
        else
            front = NULL;
        delete temp;
    } else {
        Tile* ptr = front;
        while (ptr -> getNext() != NULL) {
            if (ptr -> getNext() -> getIndex() == x) {
                Tile* temp = ptr -> getNext();
                ptr -> setNext(ptr -> getNext() -> getNext());
                delete temp;
                return;
            }
            ptr = ptr->getNext();
        }
    }
    size--;
    updateIndexes();
}
```

Comment: It's unlikely that someone would want to sift through your entire code, especially on some other site. You need to reduce your entire code to a very short [mcve], edit your question, and include your [mcve] as part of the question itself.

Comment: That list-remove has a code path whereby `size` is *not* decremented, yet you removed a node from the list. That pretty much screws your `while (size != 0)` control loop logic that is calling into this. Hopefuly you can stop throwing code at your editor long enough to see that. *Run this in a **debugger***. Xcode has one, you know.

Comment: Actually, if "size" gets out of sync, the most likely result seems to be an infinite loop, in that destructor.

Comment: Thanks, that's probably the issue.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but the destructor body only needs one of the four lines that are there.